# Pseudocode for the 'for loop'

Tags: for-loop, pseudocode, nested-for-loop

How can I write pseudocode for nested for loop and decrementing for loop? I mean can I just write "for i in 1 to n" for a decrementing loop which decrements from n to 1.
for example for this code snippet:

```
for (a=N; a>=1; a--) {
    for (b=0; b<a; b++) {
          cout<<a+b;
    }
}
```

can I write something like this:

```
for a in 1 to n
    for b in 0 to a
        print a+b
```

is this correct? or should i change something?

Comment: but how should i define its decrementing thing?

Answer (score 0):

```
for a in N to 1   
 for b in 0 to a
     print a+b
 // decrementing is shown by going from N to 1 higher -> lower
```

Comment: although I would do a-1 because a is not inclusive

Comment: I would use "downto" like it's used in the [Pascal](https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu57.html) programming language — `for a in N downto 1`